# Parsing Data in Google Sheets From an Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, text-parsing

I have thousands of rows of data in a Google Sheets File in a column that looks something like 

`[{"amountMax":49.99,"amountMin":49.99,"availability":"true","color":"Brown","currency":"USD","dateSeen":["2019-04-11T08:00:00Z"],"isSale":"false","offer":"Online only","sourceURLs":["https://www.walmart.com/ip/SadoTech-Model-CXR-Wireless-Doorbell-1-Remote-Button-2-Plugin-Receivers-Operating-500-feet-Range-50-Chimes-Batteries-Required-Receivers-Beige-Fixed-C/463989633"]}]`

I would like to be able to return the max value, the currency, the color attributes. How can I do that in Google Sheets. Ideally would like to do something like being able to retrieve the data attributes how I would normally in javascript like in this link here https://repl.it/@alexhoy/WetSlateblueDribbleware

However this does not seem to work for me when creating a function in script.google.com

For example, here is a slugify function which takes an input (cell) and turns it into a slug/handle without the need for looping. In Google Sheets I can then call =slugify(b2) and turn that value into slug form

```
/**
* Converts value to slug
* @customfunction
*/
function slugify(value) {
  /*
   * Convert the the vs in a range of cells into slugs.
   * @customfunction
   */
  let slug = '';

  slug = value.substring(0, 100).toLowerCase();
  slug = slug.replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '');
  slug = slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  Logger.log(slug);

  return slug;
}
```

I want to do the same thing without looping to parse the object data above or declaring a range of values and what not.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in a simple way like shown above without the need for declaring active spreadsheet, range values and looping.

Comment: *However this does not seem to work for me when creating a function in script.google.com* You should show that script function in your question

Answer (score 2):

The following script will give you an idea about how to approach this task.

It assumes that:

- the json data described in your question is in Cell A2.
- the max value will be inserted into cell D2
- the currency will be inserted into cell E2
- the color will be inserted into cell F2

The script uses temporary arrays to capture the values and then assign it to a 2d array.

If you have many rows of data, then you will need to create a loop. I suggest that you build the arraydata progressively, and only update the target range at the end of the loop. This will give you the most efficient outcome.

---

```
function so6031098604() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var content = JSON.parse(sheet.getRange("A2").getValue());

  // temp arrar to capture the data
  var temparray = [];
  temparray.push(content[0]["amountMax"]);
  temparray.push(content[0]["currency"]);
  temparray.push(content[0]["color"]);

  // second array to accept the row data
  var arraydata =[];
  arraydata.push(temparray)

  // define the target range
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange(2, 4, 1, 3);
  // update with the arraydata
  targetrange.setValues(arraydata);

}
```

Comment: @TheMaster Noted. I was so focused on the JSON that this didn't even occur to me. Answer revised.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution, seems overly complicated for such a simple task!

Comment: Answer updated to remove "unnecessary code". This is about as simple as it comes. I agree that it could be more simple if there was only one line of data, but you have "thousands of lines", and will need to create a loop. So which bit of the answer do you think is over complicated?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I suppose I was looking for something that did not involve a loop. Sort of like a built in excel function that you could write as =getAmountMax(A2) and then drag down to the appropriate cell

Answer (score 0):

You want a custom function that will return certain fields from a JSON array.

In the following example, the  target cell can be a single cell or an array.

This example does not use an arrayformula. The mechanics of using an arrayformula with a custom function may be something that you can research here [Custom SHEETNAME function not working in Arrayformula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129103/196152).

Note: A 30 second quota applies to the execution of a Custom function

---

```
/**
 * gets the MaxAmount, Current and Color from the data
 *
 * @param {cell reference or range} range The range to analyse.
 * @return amountMax,currency and  color
 * @customfunction
 */
function getJsonData(range) {

  //so6031098606
  // Test whether range is an array.
  if (range.map) {

  // if yes, then loop through the rows and build the row values
    var jsonLine = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
      var jsonValues=[];
      var v = JSON.parse(range[i][0]);
      jsonValues.push(v.amountMax);
      jsonValues.push(v.currency);
      jsonValues.push(v.color);

      // aggregate the row values
      jsonLine.push(jsonValues); 
   } // end i

   return jsonLine;

 } else {

   // if no, then just return a single set of values
   var v = JSON.parse(range);
   var jsonValues = [];
   jsonValues.push(v.amountMax);
   jsonValues.push(v.currency);
   jsonValues.push(v.color);
   return [jsonValues];
 } 
}
```